# Conditional statement for fail and error test outcomes in Selenium?

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, test-design

Say I have this function:

```
    def tearDown(self):
    """ clean up by closing the browser window """
    self.driver.quit()
```

I want to skip closing the browser if the test failed or errored out (so I can examine what was on the screen when the test last left off). Is this possible?

Let's say I don't even care if the browser closes, because I can do

```
self.driver.save_screenshot('path')
```

I still need the "if test failed" logic to make that happen, so I won't have to dig through hundreds of screenshots to find the failed test.

I'm using nose as my test runner (http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, your question is more about Nose than Selenium.  You want errors and failures to do something that successes do not.  I do not have any experience with Nose, but the [documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/errorclasses.html) suggests that you could write your own ErrorClass plugin that will take a screenshot when the error/failure occurs.

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe it was this simple, but this seems to work!

```
def tearDown(self):
    """ clean up by closing the browser window """
    if not Exception:  # leave failed test windows open
        self.driver.quit()
```